# Javascript tile doesn't load

Tags: javascript, html

The javascript file(sript1) doesn't load when i open the test page and they are in the same folder.(I am using sublime text).

The test page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <script src="script1.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

The script1.js page

```
var database = [
{
    username:"boss",
    password:"super"
}
];

var newFeed = [
{
    username="Bob",
    timeline="whatsssupp"
},
{
    username="Sally",
    timeline="cooooool"

}
];

var userNamePrompt= prompt("What is your username");
var passwordPropmt=prompt("Whats your password");
```

Comment: what error do you see or how do you know it is not loading, i dont think your .js does anything (yet)

Comment: @aaronlilly, `prompt` must be triggerd...

Comment: Is the `script1.js` file located in the same folder as the html file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely your JS file is loaded (and running), but it contains errors so it doesn't show the prompts as you expected it to. You are using `=` instead of `:` when assigning a value to an object (newFeed).

Test whether fixing your code works for you, like so:

```
var database = [
    {
        username: "boss",
        password: "super"
    }
];

var newFeed = [
    {
        username:"Bob",
        timeline:"whatsssupp"
    },
    {
        username:"Sally",
        timeline:"cooooool"

    }
];

var userNamePrompt = prompt("What is your username");
var passwordPropmt = prompt("Whats your password");
```

In the case that it didn't fix your issue, then it could be one of the following:

- permission issue; ensure that you have the right permissions
- the file path or name is incorrect; always double check your paths and names;
- other reasons we can not see from here

Whatever the reason might be, most browsers nowadays have something called 'Developer Tools' which can be opened using the F12 hotkey. Then you will be able to see in the console if JavaScript code goes wrong:

**Firefox**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools

**Chrome**: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

**IE**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/hh968260(v=vs.85)

**EDGE**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide

THAT error will tell you exactly what is going wrong with your setup.
Hope it helps!